# Paginated array would not show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view, kaminari

I'm rather new to Ruby on Rails so would appreciate some help

Roles have Users in my application.
When showing a role I would like to render a paginated list of user names (and as a further refactor - links to users).
Currently my HAML template is as follows

...

```
  %ul.assigned-users
    - if @role.users.present?
      - names = @role.users.collect {|u|  u.name}
      - links = Kaminari.paginate_array(names).page(params[:page]).per(20)
      = paginate links
    - else
      %p No users have this role assigned
```

...

Rendering it gives me the pagination links BUT no names.

Answer (score 0):

`Kaminari`'s `paginate_array` method does not show the values in the array.

The best way to do so is get the query paginated from the database. `Kaminari.paginate_array` in your code takes in the whole array of users from the database and then paginates it which is highly inefficient and memory consuming.

You need to add the logic to the controller. If you paginate the `@role.users` query, it is generated with `LIMIT` which is the value you assign in the `per` method and `OFFSET` which equals to `(params[:page] - 1) * per`. This gets only the number of records you need from the database.

**In your controller `app/controllers/roles_controller.rb`**

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def show
   @role = Role.find params[:id]
   @users = @role.users.page(params[:page]).per(20)
  end
end
```

**In your view `app/views/roles/show.html.haml`**

```
%ul.assigned-users
  - if @users.present?
    - @users.each do |u|
      %li=u.name
    = paginate @users
  - else
    %p No users have this role assigned
```